# Join two tables with multiple Nullable foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables
1) Airports
2) Traffic ( Having 2 foreign keys of Airports as fromAirport and ToAirport)
in Traffic table some time fromAirport is Null and some Time ToAirport
i am collecting statistics of movements but due to Null Values, my stats are not accurate.
Here is my query.

```
SELECT tr .Status,AL.Airline,A.City,
 SUM(ISNULL(Landings,0)) As Landings,  
 SUM(ISNULL(TakeOff,0)) As TakeOffs,  
 SUM(ISNULL(Landings,0) + ISNULL(TakeOff,0)) As Total_Movements  
 FROM dbo.Traffic tr 
 Inner Join   dbo.Airlines AL On tr.OPAirline = al.ID 
 INNER JOIN Airports A ON A.ID=COALESCE(tr.fromAirport, tr.ToAirport)
 WHERE (Date Between '01-Dec-2018' AND '31-Dec-2018') AND (tr.Status='Schedule')  
 GROUP By tr.Status,AL.Airline,COALESCE(tr.fromAirport, tr.ToAirport), A.City
 Order By tr.Status,AL.Airline
```

The Result i am getting is missing some movements, If i check daily base movements, that is approximately equal in landings and takeoffs.
how can i get accurate result in same style by getting missing values?

```
Status      Airline     City    Landings    TakeOffs    Total_Movements
--------    --------    ------  ---------   ----------  ---------------
Schedule    ABC         City1   20          14          34
Schedule    CDE         City2   11          11          22
Schedule    ABCDEF      City3   18          22          40
Schedule    AFGH        City4   12          14          26
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. try `GROUP BY tr.Status, AL.Airline, A.City`.

Comment: Same result still missing some movements.

Answer (score 0):

As table `Traffic` has 2 foreign keys of Airports as fromAirport and ToAirport and columns are NULLable then try to use `LEFT JOIN` and use `COUNT()` function, not `SUM()` as you need the overall quantity of `landings`, `takeoffs`:

```
 SELECT 
   tr.Status
 , AL.Airline
 , A.City
 , SUM(ISNULL(Landings,0)) As Landings
 , SUM(ISNULL(TakeOff,0)) As TakeOffs  
 , SUM(ISNULL(Landings,0) + ISNULL(TakeOff,0)) As Total_Movements  
 FROM dbo.Traffic tr 
 LEFT Join   dbo.Airlines AL On tr.OPAirline = al.ID 
 LEFT JOIN Airports A ON A.ID=COALESCE(tr.fromAirport, tr.ToAirport)
 WHERE (Date Between '01-Dec-2018' AND '31-Dec-2018') AND tr.Status='Schedule')  
 GROUP By tr.Status
       , AL.Airline
       , A.City
       , Landings
       , TakeOff
 Order By tr.Status,AL.Airline
```

Comment: by count, every city gets equal movements in landing and takeoffs and some city exceeded actual movements :) still result is not accurate

Comment: Still same results dear.
if Traffic table Takeoffs column also has null entries, will it effect the result?
My desired result is same but thing is result is missing some takeoffs in this query

Comment: @UsmanSattar could you share the sample data and desired output?

Comment: with COUNT, i get all the movements just issue is movement get doubled for each flight. like if exact movements are 20, it shows 40.

Comment: SELECT 
   Ad.Status
 , AL.Airline
 , A.City
 , COUNT(ISNULL(Landings,0)) As Landings
 , COUNT(ISNULL(TakeOff,0)) As TakeOffs  
 , COUNT(ISNULL(Landings,0) + ISNULL(TakeOff,0)) As Total_Movements  
 FROM dbo.Traffic Ad 
 LEFT Join   dbo.Airlines AL On Ad.OPAirline = al.ID 
 LEFT JOIN Airports A ON A.ID=COALESCE(ad.fromAirport,0) OR A.ID=COALESCE(ad.ToAirport,0)
 WHERE (Date Between '01-Feb-2019' AND '28-Feb-2019') AND (Ad.Status='Schedule')  
 GROUP By Ad.Status
       , AL.Airline
       , A.City
 Order By Ad.Status,AL.Airline

"getting all movements,but doubling them"

Comment: @UsmanSattar please, see my updated answer. Could you share data with tables and desired result?

Comment: thank you for your response. i have done that with union.
 with structure like
select a, SUM(ISNULL(b,0)), SUM(ISNULL(c,0)) from
( select a,COUNT(ISNULL(b,0)), 0 as c
UNION
select a , 0 as b, COUNT(ISNULL(c,0))
)aa
group by a